# Find the value of $\int_0^1dx \int_x^{1-x}f(t)\ dt$ for arbitrary continuous function $f$?

Tags: real-analysis

let $f$ be continuous $\forall x$

Find the value of $$\int_0^1dx \int_x^{1-x}f(t)dt$$

Okay I couldn't find the value of this. I mean in what form do they want to value so that I can answer the question "Can you explain the answer you obtain?"

What? I have no idea, This is just the double integral of f(t) over some region in $R^2$ - It's the volume of the curve depicted by $f(t)$ in $R^3$ which has the cross-section as given in the integrand in $R^2$

What do they exactly want from me here any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral is zero.

Suppose $f$ has antiderivative $F$. Then the value is
$$\int_0^1(F(1-x) - F(x))\; dx$$
Break this into two integrals, and a simple substitution shows this is a difference of identical integrals, so zero:

$$u=1-x \implies dx=-du$$
$$x=0\implies u=1, x=1\implies u=0$$
$$\int_0^1F(1-x)\; dx = \int_1^0-F(u)\; du = \int_0^1F(u)\; du$$
so
$$\int_0^1(F(1-x) - F(x))\; dx = \int_0^1F(u)\; du - \int_0^1F(x)\; dx = 0$$
(**Bonus:** Where do you think continuity of $f$ is used?)

Comment: Ah cheater, I'm trying to do this the hard way.

Comment: It's also worth taking a look at the geometric area this is integrating, the zero result is clear there too.

Comment: At taking the integral itself,
Doing substitution etc.

Comment: @Xenidia Nah, its fine, I figured it out myself

Comment: @SimpleArt : Not cheating, that's what the continuity assumption gets me.

Comment: Does continuity implie existence of primitive?

Comment: @SimpleArt : Yes, every continuous function $f$ has an antiderivative $F$. That antiderivative is differentiable, and its derivative is the original function $(F' = f)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_x^{1-x}f(t)\ dt\ dx&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_x^{1-x}f(t)\ dt\ dx+\int_{1/2}^1\int_x^{1-x}f(t)\ dt\ dx\\&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_x^{1-x}f(t)\ dt\ dx-\int_{1/2}^0\int_{1-u}^{u}f(t)\ dt\ du\tag{$u=1-x$}\\&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_x^{1-x}f(t)\ dt\ dx-\int_0^{1/2}\int_{u}^{1-u}f(t)\ dt\ du\\&=I-I\\&=0\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Sketch a region of integration and change the order.